# Changing String Format

Tags: c#

I am being passed the string `"1/20/2015 8:01:25 PM"` and I need to remove the `:25` in the seconds part of the string making it `"1/20/2015 8:01 PM"`. This will eventually be used on many date strings so it will need to work for a string like `"11/11/2011 11:11:11 PM"` and convert it to `"11/11/2011 11:11 PM"` It is all being done in C# and any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Why don't convert this string to DateTime, zero the seconds and convert back?

Comment: Are you guaranteed to be given the same date/time format every time?

Comment: Yes it will always be formatted the same way

Comment: Usual recommendation: please use ISO8601 format for sending date/time values as text if possible. http://xkcd.com/1179/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse the string into a `DateTime`, then `.ToString()` the date to get the format you want.

```
var myString = "1/20/2015 8:01:25 PM";
var asDate = DateTime.Parse(myString);
var resultingString = asDate.ToString("M/dd/yyyy h:mm tt");
```

Refer to [this MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) article for date format strings

Comment: This makes assumptions about the current culture - Depending on the environments this code may be running in this may not be a safe assumption to make.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your *string* date to `DateTime` object and then apply custom format like:

```
var dateTimeObj = DateTime.ParseExact("1/20/2015 8:01:25 PM", "M/d/yyyy h:m:s tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var output = dateTimeObj.ToString("M/d/yyyy hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Notice the single `d`,`M`,`h`, `m` and `s` in parsing, since that could be used for single as well as double digits values.

Answer (score 1):

The trick to this is knowing that your input string will *always* be formatted this same way.

If it is, you could simply do this:

```
string s = "1/20/2015 8:01:25 PM";
string s2 = s.Substring(0, s.Length - 6) + s.Substring(s.Length - 3);
```

A more reliable approach might be to use `DateTime.Parse()` to convert to a `DateTime` and then format it however you want. Or better yet, keep the value in a `DateTime` variable until you need to format it the way you want.

Comment: @ThomasKrojer Note that this answer would keep "AM" if necessary, rather than blinding appending "PM".

Comment: Yeah ...I saw it already, and still living in a 24 hour region

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) and [DateTime.ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) with [custom format strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) to do that.